# Scatterplot of Year-On-Year Correlation of Data in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have some yearly football data that I would like to test to see if certain team metrics are repeatable in the next year. My data is in a data.frame and looks something like this:

```
                    y2003    y2004    y2005
Team 1           51.95455 51.00000 53.59091   
Team 2           54.18182 56.31818 49.09091   
Team 3           48.68182 46.86364 49.22727   
Team 4           50.86364 47.68182 48.72727
```

What I want to be able to do is scatterplot this with "Year n" on the x-axis and "Year n+1" on the y-axis. So for example 2003 vs. 2004, 2004 vs. 2005, 2005 vs. 2006 etc. all on the same plot.

I would then like to be able to draw a line of best fit to see how strong the correlation is, whether it is repeatable or not.

What is the best way to do this in R with ggplot2? I can get the initial plot with:

```
 p=ggplot(df,aes(y2003,y2004))
 p + geom_point()
```

Then do I just have to add them all manually? Is there an inbuilt function for this sort of thing? And if I add them all one-by-one how will I get the best fit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a data frame with a row for each team-year combination, containing the data for that year and the next year as well as the team name. You can actually get this without any split-apply-combine manipulation using base R functions:

```
(to.plot <- data.frame(yearN=unlist(df[-ncol(df)]),
                       yearNp1=unlist(df[-1]),
                       team=rep(row.names(df), ncol(df)-1)))
#           yearN  yearNp1  team
# y20031 51.95455 51.00000 Team1
# y20032 54.18182 56.31818 Team2
# y20033 48.68182 46.86364 Team3
# y20034 50.86364 47.68182 Team4
# y20041 51.00000 53.59091 Team1
# y20042 56.31818 49.09091 Team2
# y20043 46.86364 49.22727 Team3
# y20044 47.68182 48.72727 Team4
```

Basically this code converts all but the last column of `df` into a vector (using `unlist`), storing them in variable `yearN`. The next year can be obtained by grabbing all but the first column of `df` into a vector. Finally, the team name can be obtained as a repeated sequence of the row names of `df`.

Getting a line of best fit is a simple linear regression model:

```
(coefs <- coef(lm(yearNp1~yearN, data=to.plot)))
# (Intercept)       yearN 
#  28.3611927   0.4308978
```

Now `ggplot` can be used as usual for plotting:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(to.plot, aes(x=yearN, y=yearNp1, col=team)) + geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept=coefs[1], slope=coefs[2])
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to make data ggplot "friendly", then it is easy:

```
df <- read.table(text=" y2003   y2004   y2005
Team1   51.95455    51  53.59091
                 Team2  54.18182    56.31818    49.09091
                 Team3  48.68182    46.86364    49.22727
                 Team4  50.86364    47.68182    48.72727
                 ")

#make data ggplot friendly
mycomb <- combn(colnames(df),2)
plotDat <- do.call(rbind,
                   lapply(1:ncol(mycomb),function(i){
                     res <- df[,mycomb[,i]]
                     colnames(res) <- c("x","y")
                     res$Group <- paste(mycomb[,i],collapse="-")
                     res
                   }))

#plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plotDat,aes(x,y,col=Group)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]